# How can we send a GET request to a python bottle server without using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, bottle

This is the simple HTML page with a text box and a search button

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" name="queryString"><br>
<button type="button" name="searchButton">Search</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Initially, the above HTML page is served by a bottle server (I am going to omit the code), and then I wish to process the search queryString using:

```
@route('/', method = 'GET')
def processSearch():
    queryString = request.forms.get("queryString")
    print 'queryString is:', keyword
    return 'processSearch() executed'
```

My question is: without a Javascript onclick listener function (which would make an AJAX call), is it possible to click on the search button and fire a GET request which starts executing processSearch()?

**Note**: I am aware POST is ideal for form data submission, but I am still interested to know if this will work.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Without Javascript, you can only send something to the server by clicking on a link or submitting a form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a form, and change the button to a `submit` input:

```
<form action="yourscript.py" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="queryString"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="searchButton" value="Search">
</form>
```